# Leer un archivo txt y aplicarle una font

Tags: html, css

estoy intentando hacer con HTML y CSS, un código que me permita leer un archivo txt, extraer el texto que está guardado ahí, y luego ponerlo en la pagina web con una font, y no puedo. No soy programador avanzado, se apenas la base.

```css
<style type="text/css">
 @font-face {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  src: url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700) format("truetype");
 }
 p.montserrat { 
  font-family: "Montserrat", Verdana, Tahoma;
 }
</style>

<div class="montserrat" style="overflow: hidden; float: left;">
 <object type="text/plain" data="sub.txt" width="400" height="300"></object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso no basta usar HTML o JavaScript en el mejor caso. Deberías de usar PHP. La función include() de php te va a servir, acá te dejo como funciona http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: Lo estaré mirando, gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Como ya lo dijeron debes de usar algun lenguaje para que puedas leer un archivo txt podria ser  PHP

```
<?php
```

$file = fopen("1.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
{
echo fgets($file). "
";
}
fclose($file);
?>

DONDE 
fgets($file) ES EL TEXTO DE 1.txt
eso lo puedes poner en cualquier lugar de tu pagina.

Comment: Dale, lo voy a estar probando, muchas gracias por la ayuda!